# simplex algorithm - importance of basic solution?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

Importance of basic solution in simplex algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all variables (structural and logical) are non-negative (i.e. `x>=0` and slacks `s>=0`) then all non-basic variables are equal to zero. As they are fixed to zero we only have to solve for the `m` basic variables.

Essentially we have to solve

```
A x = b
```

Unfortunately this is a non-square system of equations (after adding slacks we always have more columns than rows). In LPs we can form a basic solution and partition this into

```
B x_B + N x_N = b
```

After setting `x_N = 0` we have just a square system of linear equations with solution:

```
x_B = inv(B) b
```

There is a fundamental theorem that says we can restrict the search to only basic solutions i.e. solutions that can be partitioned in basic and non-basic variables

```
x = [ x_B ]
    [ x_N ]
```

with `x_B >= 0` and `x_N = 0`.

For more info open a book about Linear Programming; a very good one is [Vanderbei](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461476291).

Comment: Thank you @Erwin!